# Change paper-material elevation on paper-fab hover (Polymer 1.0)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I'm trying to make a floating add button in my Polymer 1.0 app with pretty much similar functionality to Google Inbox's floating add button.  First question then:

To achieve similar functionality, I'm currently using the `paper-fab` element and `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` js functions as follows:

```
<paper-fab id="addBtn" icon="add" class="fab red" onmouseover="hoverOver(this)" onmouseout="hoverOut(this)"></paper-fab>

<script>

    hoverOver = function(srcElement) {
        srcElement.querySelector("paper-material").elevation = 4;
    };

    hoverOut = function(srcElement) {
        srcElement.querySelector("paper-material").elevation = 0;
    };

</script>
```

Is this the recommended approach, or is there a slicker, more 'polymerized' way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by using *css* only.

```
paper-fab::shadow > paper-material {
    @apply(--shadow-none);
}

paper-fab::shadow > paper-material:hover {
    @apply(--shadow-elevation-8dp);
}
```

In the source code of the `paper-material` element, you can see that the `elevation` attribute is just for setting the the `box-shadow` style on the element. So instead of updating the attribute in *js* (which then sets the *css*), you can simply update the same thing directly in *css*.

```
<dom-module id="paper-material">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      @apply(--shadow-transition);
    }

    :host([elevation="1"]) {
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-2dp);
    }

    :host([elevation="2"]) {
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-4dp);
    }

    :host([elevation="3"]) {
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-6dp);
    }

    :host([elevation="4"]) {
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-8dp);
    }

    :host([elevation="5"]) {
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-16dp);
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin.  IINM, I read somewhere that @apply is still 'experimental', and also that 'shadow' is going to be deprecated?  Am I wrong on that?  If not, is this a safe approach to take?

Comment: @sinjins, it's widely used atm but if it's indeed changed in the future, you can always update it right? :) Also, in `shadow.html`, you will find that `--shadow-elevation-8dp` is simply `box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
                  0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);` You can replace it all with the actual native css `box-shadow`.

Comment: Indeed.  Or I could stay with my approach, so that when the Polymer team updates their `paper-material` element to make it compliant when 'shadow' is about to become deprecated, all I would have to do is a bower update of that element and no code changes on my end.  Is that sound logic?

Comment: If styling and animations/transitions could be done only with *css*, I would never use `js`. If you want to be safe, just replace `@apply(--shadow-elevation-8dp);` with `box-shadow: ...`. This is a much better approach IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you'd like to use html, ensure that the paper material has the attribute "animated" set to "true"

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is put in `<style>` directly in dom-module of your element.html

```
 paper-button:hover{
        @apply(--shadow-elevation-6dp);
    }
```

May change the dp for elevation . Hope helps